# Weblogic Spring application gives error for css and js

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I deploy application in weblogic server it deployed success.
After deployment I tried to access application like welcome.do it shows content with main stream url response come back but all js and css file not download gives 500 internal server error for js and css.

I have added mime configuration in web.xml as well as weblogic mime properties but not working still.

This application is working in other web server fine.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question with that refreshed knowledge.

Comment: you need to share your server logs for that. Your server is crashing at some point.